# My application doesn't work since I changed the url of the web service

Tags: vb.net, web-services, console, certificate

Since August 1st, the url of the web service changed, the application was running fine with the previous url, but with the new one, the application works for 1 user, the 2 other ones encounter this error message :

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel
>   with authority 'e-factura.sunat.gob.pe'

My project is a console one, in it, I use a certificate file to sign a xml file, the certificate is on a server, it's not installed on the certificate store. Moreover, to consume the web service, a wsse:security authentication is required.
My app.config file is this one (I did hide the wsse:security credentials) :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
<source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
    <listeners>
      <add name="FileLog"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<switches>
  <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information"/>
</switches>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="FileLog" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
</sharedListeners>
 </system.diagnostics>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BillServicePortBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="secured">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://e-factura.sunat.gob.pe:443/ol-ti-itcpfegem/billService"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BillServicePortBinding"
      contract="Production.billService" name="BillServicePort" >
    <headers>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken >
          <wsse:Username>XXXXXXXX</wsse:Username>
          <wsse:Password Type='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText'>XXXXXX</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
    </headers>
  </endpoint>
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have no idea what to do to solve the problem, moreover, I can't consume the web service on my machine (the web service is used to sent real invoices to tax office).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I connected to their server, I ran on there Internet Explorer, I added the address of the web server to the trusted sites list.
I asked then each use to do the same on their PC, so far, I got a feedback from one of them who confirmed the application is now working.